# Excel Conditional Formatting to recognise specific case sensitive text

Tags: excel, highlight, case-sensitive, exact-match

I have this issue with Highlighting of Cells in the Ms Excel worksheet. The range of cells required is, lets say A1 to D10. Cells in this range will be highlighted Red only if it is entered with a lower case text x. If any other text (even a capital X) is entered, that particular cell must be Red. So each cells in that range can remain normal when BLANK and also when entered with lower case x. But if any input is entered other than the lower case x, that cells must turn Red. Can anyone please suggest way out with the Conditional Formatting for this issue.

Tried EXACT(x,A1:D10), with and without quotations and all varuous combinations of FIND, MATCH, SEARCH, etc, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional format will change the cell reference automatically. You are not required to include the whole range in the formula. That only creates a formula error.
Simply EXACT("x",A1) should be fine for string - x.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But then I will have to repeat the sequence for all cells. Actually the cells that require this condition of text identification is from A1 to AX1200. That will be a lot of entries manually. Hence I tried EXACT("x",A1:AX1200) but it did not help. I also made section thinking that the entire range may be too larga and hence tried EXACT("x",A1:AX50). No luck there, too.

Comment: YES!  YES! YES! Victor, you are a life saver. Initially, I did not understand what you meant. But I tried it out and it worked. Only I added one more command to ignore the BLANK cells and gave it a STOP. The sheet is delivering results as required. PERFECT. Thanks Victor. My query is solved.